# How do I specify net.sf.json-lib#json-lib#2.3 in Ivy or Maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, ivy

I am in the middle of converting over our build system from Ant to Ant with Ivy, and have run into an issue specifying a particular jar we need.

- **groupId**: net.sf.json-lib
- **artifactId**: json-lib
- **version**: 2.3

I specified it in Ivy as:

```
<dependency org="net.sf.json-lib"  artifact="json-lib"
    rev="2.3"     conf="compile->default"/>
```

And got the following error:

```
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://buildl01.tcprod.local/artifactory/libs-release/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.3/json-lib-2.3.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3!json-lib.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Notice Ivy tried to download the file `json-lib-2.3.jar` from the repository.

I did a search on the [Central Maven Repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.json-lib%7Cjson-lib%7C2.3%7Cjar) and found that the artifact isn't called `json-lib-2.3.jar` but either `json-lib-2.3-jdk-13.jar` or `json-lib-2.3-jdk-15.jar`.

The problem is the way the name of the artifact is specified. The version number appears in the **middle** of the jar name. If the artifact was `json-lib-jdk-15-2.4.jar, I could do this:

```
<dependency org="net.sf.json-lib"  artifact="json-lib"
    rev="2.3"     conf="compile->default">
    <artifact name="json-lib-jdk-15"/>
</dependency>
```

How can I specify this jar for downloading?

Comment: I just found out that this question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6942989/1374678

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "thing" at the end of the jar name is called the *classifier*. It is used to target specific platforms or to provide sources or Javadoc.

To get the jar, you need to define the classifier like this:

```
<ivy-module version='2.0' xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
...
<dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" artifact="json-lib" rev="2.3"conf="compile->default">
    <artifact name="json-lib" type="jar" m:classifier="jdk15"/>
</dependency>
```

Read [this article](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.ch/2011/09/how-to-use-mclassifier-in-apache-ivy.html) for more information.

Comment: Now I'm getting _The prefix "m" for attribute "m:classifier" associated with an element type "dependency" is not bound_. I bet I have to munge my ivysettings.xml somehow first.

Comment: Thanks. The answer you [pointed to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6942989/1374678) did work.