# Resolving specific scope from maven repository using ivy

Tags: maven, gradle, scope, ivy, resolve

I have published a maven artifact using gradle(with maven-publish plugin) the files look like this:

```
foo-1.0.0.pom
foo-1.0.0.jar
foo-sources-1.0.0.jar
foo-barbaz-1.0.0.zip // <- this
```

I want to get the zip file(marked) with scope barbaz using ivy, but when I resolve it the generated ivy.xml does not contain this artifact

Notice:

1. that the pom file has only the dependencies.
2. I have no experience with maven, only ant+ivy and gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following dependency declaration, detailing the [remote artifact](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html) you want downloaded:

```
<ivy-module version='2.0' xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">

  <dependency org="com.myorg" name="foo" rev="1.0.0">
    <artifact name="foo" type="zip" e:classifier="barbaz"/>
  </dependency>

</ivy-module>
```

---

Update:

- [Ivy - Can't download because POM file and the JAR file name aren't matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942989/ivy-cant-download-because-pom-file-and-the-jar-file-name-arent-matching-patt/6949758#6949758)